# Why is my y value not displayed in the time series (bar plot)?

Tags: ggplot2, time-series, bar-chart

So I've created a time series event. I'd like to plot my NS data on the y axes. Unfortunately it's not working and I can't figure out why. I'd like to plot it as a bar plot. The x value input should be my newly created DateTime. Any notes?

```
library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)
  Versuch3 <- data.frame(date = c("1.1.2015", "2.1.2015", "3.1.2015"), 
                         time = c("06:12:03", "08:23:45", "15:40:32"),
                         NS = c("0.3", "0.4", "0.6"),
                         status = c("0", "1", "0"))
  Versuch3$DateTime <- paste(Versuch3$date,Versuch3$time,sep =" ")
  Versuch3$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Versuch3$DateTime, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))

  Versuch3$NS <- as.integer(Versuch3$NS)

  dtLimits <- c(as.POSIXct("2014-12-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-07-01 00:00:00"))

  #plot
  ggplot(data = Versuch3, aes(x=DateTime, y=NS)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=status), width = 3) +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month",
                 labels = date_format("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"),
                 limits = dtLimits) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

Comment: Try adding `position = "dodge"` to `geom_bar`.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry. Checked again. Simply removing `width=3` gives me three small bars side by side.

Comment: Thank you! Makes actually sense :)